# Linkedin Like Box widget with faces?

Tags: widget, linkedin-api

I search Linkedin Like Box. It should be similar as FB like box. I mean share button + faces. But I can't find this widget or code.

Do you have examples of Linkedin share widget (like box) with faces, or it's my illusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pre-built 'like' box for LinkedIn - [these are all of the available plugins](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins). You would need to use the [LinkedIn APIs](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest) and build one from scratch.